# google maps markers not showing

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers

I think I know what the bug is: latitude and longitude of markers is Nan instead of coordinates...But why???
If I check the title (`alert(marker.markerTitle);`) it has the right values
If I check the position (`alert(marker.position);`) it returns NaN

The HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      var serviceUrl = {"markers":[{markerLatitude:"12,5741",markerLongitude:"55,70612",markerTitle:"Krudttønden"},{markerLatitude:"11,84656",markerLongitude:"55,96518",markerTitle:"Halsnæs bryghus"},]}
    </script>
                        <div id="google-map"></div>
```

The Script:

```
 if (jQuery('#google-map')[0]) {
  var map_canvas = document.getElementById('google-map');

  var startPosition = new google.maps.LatLng('55.92', '10.90');
  var mapOptions = { center: startPosition, zoom: 8, streetViewControl: true, panControl: true, draggable: true, mapTypeControl: true, maxZoom: 16, minZoom: 3 };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, mapOptions);

  for (var i = 0; i < serviceUrl.markers.length; i++) {
    var data = serviceUrl.markers[i];
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: '<div class="info-window"><h3>' + data.markerTitle + '</h3><p class="teaser"></p></a></div>'

    });

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(data.markerLatitude, data.markerLongitude),
      map: map,
      title: data.markerTitle,
      infowindows: infowindow
    });

    //alert(marker.position);
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
      this.infowindows.open(map, this);
    });
  }
  test = serviceUrl;
  console.log(test.markers[0].markerLatitude);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because input values are strings

```
markerLatitude:"12,5741", markerLongitude:"55,70612"
```

you have to use `parseFloat()` of data when you create markers: `LatLng()` method expects numbers. Your code should be:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(data.markerLatitude), 
                                   parseFloat(data.markerLongitude)),
  map: map,
  title: data.markerTitle,
  infowindows: infowindow
});
```